# ES6 with vim -- strange indentation with () => ()

Tags: vim, ecmascript-6

The ES6 implicit return is useful for keeping unnecessary clutter out of function definitions and helps enforce the writing of 'pure components' in React.

However, the indentation doesn't play nicely with Vim, when I define the function **with parentheses** for the return block and hit enter, I wind up with **this state**:

```
const Component = () => (

        )
```

When I hit enter Vim is indenting the closing paren by *two whole tab lengths* (8 spaces in this case).

But when I do a 'normal' function **with curly braces** I get **the state I want**:

```
const Component = () => {

}
```

What gives!? I have the following three vim indentation settings enabled:

```
set autoindent
set copyindent
set preserveindent
```

Any idea what might be wrong or what settings I could look into to fix?

Comment: It's hard to read "Implicit" and "enforcing" in the same sentence and keep a straight face.

Comment: Why? Is it redundant?

Answer (score 2):

Some file types (including .c, .js, and others) have auto completion commands defined on Vim's autoload directory (do `:e $VIM/vimxx/autoload/` to get a list of these files, replace `xx` with your Vim version). Other auto completion commands are defined via plugins.

For your case I'd suggest to define an autocommand:

```
autocmd! InsertEnter *.js imap (<cr> (<cr><cr>)<up>
```

replacing `*.js` with the file type you're working with.